# Decode 96 column punch card

Tags: binary-analysis, digital-forensics

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I can't seem to find it anywhere on the internet: How do I read a 96 column IBM system/3 punch card?

I am doing an exercise but I can't seem to find a tutorial for this...thanks in advance :)

Comment: What more than https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card#IBM_96-column_punched_card_format do you need?

Answer (score -1):

The page [The Punched Card](http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/cardint.htm) as extensive information on the history of punched cards and the encodings used. It contains everything that's necessary for decoding the IBM 96-column cards.